# How to drag finger across 2 views and know which view it is on at all times

Tags: ios, swift, view, touch

Okay so  what I'm trying to figure out is how to allow the user to touch a view, drag their finger across the view to another view, and always know which view they are dragging across.  So if they go back and forth you can constantly print which view they are currently dragging their finger on. The hard part about this is that the views are in two separate table view cells.  I originally didn't mention that because I didn't think it would make a difference, but everything I try isn't working because of them being in table cells.

Answer (score 1):

While the user keeps dragging you can use `touchMoved` in the parent view or the `viewController`, then you can use the method `hitTest:inPoint` which will return the view that is under the point.

Here is an example from a `viewController`:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // first get the location in the parent view
    let location = touches.first!.locationInView(self.view)

    // ask the parent view to give you the subview falling under the location 
    let view = self.view.hitTest(location, withEvent: event)

    // do what you want with it
    print("View: %@", NSStringFromClass((view?.classForCoder)!))
}
```

**NOTE**: All your subviews must have `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @wayne all subviews must have userInteraction enabled to work with hitTest

Comment: This is not printing anything

Comment: What do you mean not printing anything, you should get something in the consul

Comment: It may be because the views are in table cells.

Comment: in the view controller, trying to put it in the cell class now. never worked with stuff like this

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `UIControl` class, make your views as subclass of `UIControl`

Now add action for your views with control event `TouchDragInside` `( UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)`. Then whenever you drag inside the view this action method will be called.

You can also know when dragging exited by using control event  `UIControlEvents.TouchDragExit`

[image: FYI]

Edit: 
To detect the touch, when we start drag from one we to another view we can use action with  `UIControlEvents.TouchDragOutside` control event.Use combination of `TouchDragInside` and `TouchDragOutside` control events for the two views to detect the touch when we dragged from one view to another view.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for! I have to finish a different part before I can actually try it but it looks right so I checked it as correct answer :)

Comment: If I already have a class for the view, do i just make that class UIControl instead of UIView class?

Comment: Okay so I got this working and it does so the thing in the function.  The only problem is when it drags off one view onto another, it's not starting touch on the other view.  It is doing what is in the function but how do I starttouch on the other view?